# Run script on a webhosting server

Tags: python, web, webserver, exe

I built a website in plain HTML and CSS. For quicker modification of the contents in the HTML file, I wrote a python script to dynamically change the file (open file, write to it, close). Is it possible to run this script or an executable file on a web hosting server in order to modify the HTML file? (I know, it might not be the best approach to the problem).

Comment: Use VDS. Those are virtual machines on which you can do everything.

Comment: Oh okay. Going to do some research on it, thanks!:)

Comment: @GeeEm don't ask for recomendation in stackoverflow :)

Comment: @koceeng okay, good to know :)